# alert view automatically dismissed in ios13 in appdelegate and its working fine in ios11

Tags: ios13

alert view automatically dismissed ios13 in appdelegate and its working fine in ios11 and issue happened only with ios13

let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "messageTitle", message:"notificationMessage", preferredStyle: .alert)

```
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1;
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please see [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=uialertcontroller%20uiwindow). This has been asked and answered a few times already.

Comment: Nothing seems working.If you have working solution please share

Comment: The proper solution is to not use a new window just to show an alert controller. Present it like any other view controller.

Comment: Thanks bro.got it

Answer (score 1):

If you create new UIWindow, you should hold it like a property because "alertWindow" will be destroyed in the end of the method where it was created. Another case you can get the window `guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }` and use it.